# Read the table data from the PDF file and save in the MySQL database as it is

Tags: java, mysql

[image]I have a requirement to read the value form a PDF file and save the result in a db.
I have converted Pdf to text .
Now the  text data looks like this:

```js
      Test Name         Results    Units Bio. Ref. Interval

LIPID PROFILE, BASIC, SERUM

    Cholesterol Total   166.00      mg/dL        <200.00 
    Triglycerides       118.00      mg/dL        <150.00
```

My requirement is to read the table data from the Pdf file  and save in the MySQL database as it is.

Comment: what is the type of file, .txt , .pdf etc?

Comment: yes now it's in text format .. i have converted pdf into text file

Comment: Okay give me some time, I will definitely give you the solution

Answer (score 0):

use java io to read the text file and jdbc to safe the information in the mysql via sql.